# Passing Page Number To Pubmed

Tags: url, search, parameters, pubmed

i am working on a project to retrieve records from pubmed and it is working on fine, the problem i have is i need to precise through the url which page number to retrieve from pubmed corresponding to a certain term.

the url : http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=heart
will return the first 20 records for heart if i want to retrieve the next 20 records, what can i do?

Can't i precise in the url which page to retrieve???

ie, http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=heart&page=2 // or smthg like that!

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be scripting against the web interface. Pubmed offers a webservice called [ESearch](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/query/static/esearch_help.html) to retrieve the information.